# Deploying contents of a source code directory to a server.

Tags: ant, bamboo

I'm trying to create a build that:

1. checks out my source code from Stash (complete)
2. grabs files out of a directory
3. deploys those files to my server (sort of complete)

The file structure is:

```
/dev/stuff.to.deploy
/random.file
/random.file
```

When I create the artifact, and deploy it, it always includes the "dev" folder. So my server looks like:

> /root/dev/stuff.to.deploy

What I want, is to copy the *contents* of the dev folder and place them in my server's root directory so that it looks like:

> /root/stuff.to.deploy

Comment: You haven't specified which SCM you are using. CI tools likek bamboo would support the checking out of code.

Comment: Sorry. Bamboo checks out code from our git repo which is housed in Stash.

Comment: I'm able to check out the code and deploy it fine. But it deploys the "dev" folder onto the server. I want to deploy the contents of the dev into the root directory on the server.

Comment: What kind of artifact you are creating? I think its a tar? Maybe your command is wrong, are you using a bash script to create the artifact?

Comment: The artifact was a full checkout of a build. I ended up solving it by having my build file (ant) create the structure I was looking for.